# jQuery effects run smoothly, but sometimes get jumpy - why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have been playing with a few jQuery effects and when they run smoothly look pretty neat, but sometimes (at random times when the script is invoked) the effects lock up and jump to the end result.

```
//--Expand Panel
$(".open-menu").live('click', function(){
    $("#wrap").css({ 'height' : newH + 'px' });
    $(".mini-menu").fadeOut(500);
    $("#headerCompany").animate({
        marginLeft: '+=142'
    }, 650);
    $("#avatar_box").fadeIn(650);
    $("#pinboard").fadeIn(550);
    $("div#centerHeader").slideDown("slow");
    $("#toggle-pinboard a").removeClass("open-menu").addClass("close-menu");
    return false;
});
// Collapse Panel
$(".close-menu").live('click', function(){
    $("#wrap").css({ 'height' : newH + 'px' });
    $("#avatar_box").fadeOut(550);
    $("#pinboard").fadeOut(550);
    $("#headerCompany").animate({
        marginLeft: '-=142'
    }, 650);
    $("div#centerHeader").slideUp(750).delay(300);
    $.post('resources/ajax/ajax.php', {
        action: 'mini_menu'
    }, function(menu){
        $("#mini-menu").hide().html(menu).addClass("mini-menu").fadeIn(1500);
    });
    $("#toggle-pinboard a").removeClass("close-menu").addClass("open-menu");
    return false;
});
```

PHP:

```
switch($post['action']) {
    case 'mini_menu':
        echo "<nav>
                <a href='/' class='dashboard-menu-link'>Dashboard</a>
                 | <a href='contacts.php'>Contacts</a>
                 | <a href='mail.php'>Mail</a>
                 | <a href='files.php' class='files-menu-link'>Files</a>
                 | <a href='toolbox.php' id='toolbox-menu-link'>Toolbox</a>
                 | <a href='agenda.php' id='agenda-menu-link'>Agenda</a>
                 | <a href='settings.php' id='settings-menu-link'>Settings</a>
            </nav>";
    break;
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="header">
        <div id="topHeader">
            <div id="topHeaderGroup">
                <div id="headerCompany">
                    <span><b><?=$company;?></b></span>
                </div>
    -------->>>     <span id="mini-menu"></span> <<<--------
                <div id="toggle-pinboard">
                    <a id="toggle-menu" class="close-menu" href="#"><span></span></a>
                </div>
                <div id="headerWelcomeAccount">
                    <div class="nav_profile_menu" >
                        <a href="helix-007"><span class="top-header-color-change">View My Profile</span></a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                        <a href="logout.php"><span class="top-header-color-change">Logout</span></a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                        <a href="#" class="menu_drop"><span class="top-header-color-change">My Account</span></a>
                    </div><!-- end nav_profile_menu -->
                </div><!-- end headerWelcomeAccount -->
            </div><!-- end topHeaderGroup -->
        </div><!-- end topHeader -->

        <div id="centerHeader">
            <div id="header_container">
                <div id="avatar_box" class="border trans_white_gloss"></div>
                <div id="pinboard"></div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end centerHeader -->
    </div><!-- END HEADER -->
```

CSS:

```
.mini-menu {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
    height: <?=$header_top_height;?>px;
    /*float: left;*/
    color: #FFF;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.mini-menu a{
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Tested in FireFox 3.6 with firebug on

Comment: Need more details: what browser(s)? Did you try with less effects? You currently run five different effects in the same time, what happens when you have only 2 or 3?

Comment: ya true, is there a way to consolidate all 5ish effects?

Comment: @s2x when commenting on other member comment, use `@` to notify that member. If relevant, you can run the effect one after the other instead of in parallel - if you want let me know and I'll post code for this.

Comment: I leave comments under the person that I am commenting to, hmmm i  was actually responding to your comment Shadow Wizard sorry if I was unclear. What do you mean tho by running them one after another?

Comment: @s2x the only reason I see your comments is I follow your question.. most people are not doing this so will never see such comments unless you use `@` to notify them. One after the other I mean `.mini-menu` will first fade out, and only when it finish fading out `headerCompany` will start animating etc.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - Ah, I learn something new everyday. Didn't know Stackoverflow had that feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Probably**

Problem could be with your **hardware configuration, browser version**

You can check effect on multiple platforms if problem exist then we need your full code with html.